# How to run a <script> when innerHTML is changed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, innerhtml

I have a `<script>` tag, and I want the script tag to run whenever the `innerHTML` of that script tag is changed. I don't care if the solution is in HTML or JS or JQuery.

Here is my code (With JQuery 3.4.1):

```
<script id="sc"></script>

<script>
var sc = $('#sc');

function runScript () {
  sc.html('console.log("Hello World");');
}
runScript();
```

I think the reason is because the script tag is run once at the beginning, and then never again, but I could be mistaken. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your syntax is still wrong. This is not how you do it. Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible and your syntax is wrong.
you need to learn some knowledge about the rendering of the web and how the web interacts with javascript.
visit https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/adding-interactivity-with-javascript

Comment: Agree with you. The OP is mixing up so many things with HTML and JS. Please see my comments in the answer.